# Copy type arguments of org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ParameterizedType

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, parameterized-types

I am trying to copy the type arguments from an existing `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ParameterizedType` to a newly created one.
The problem is that you cannot just add the type arguments from one type to another one because the arguments already have a parent.

This is my code:

```
AST ast = ... // some ast 
Type oldType = ... // existing type from ast
String name = ... // The name of the new type
Type newType = ast.newSimpleType(ast.newName(name));
if (oldType.isParameterizedType()) {
    ParameterizedType newParameterizedType = ast.newParameterizedType(newType);
    for (Object type : ((ParameterizedType) oldType).typeArguments()) {
         newParameterizedType.typeArguments().add(type); // throws illegal argument exception at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.checkNewChild(ASTNode.java:2087)
    }
    newType = newParameterizedType; // use parameterized type
}
```

How can I copy the type arguments of the old type without making the mistake which I currently make in the loop?

Comment: Have you tried the `copySubtree` or `delete` approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425345/checknewchild-throws-error-when-lowering-jdt-code)?

Comment: Using `delete()` worked great! I really should have known this solution. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Excellent! Glad it worked. I can't mark this as a dupe since the other question doesn't have an answer marked as accepted, so I'll leave it there. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Brian suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284405/copy-type-arguments-of-org-eclipse-jdt-core-dom-parameterizedtype#comment85572415_49284405), using `delete()` solved that problem. This was originally proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425345/checknewchild-throws-error-when-lowering-jdt-code). The type arguments from an existing `ParameterizedType` first have to be removed from the AST before adding them to a newly created `ParameterizedType`. This pertains to every `ASTNode`.

This is my solution using `delete()`:

```
AST ast = ... // some ast 
Type oldType = ... // existing type from ast
String name = ... // The name of the new type
Type newType = ast.newSimpleType(ast.newName(name));
if (oldType.isParameterizedType()) {
    ParameterizedType newParameterizedType = ast.newParameterizedType(newType);
    for (Object type : ((ParameterizedType) oldType).typeArguments()) {
         type.remove(); // <-- THIS LINE SOLVES THE PROBLEM
         newParameterizedType.typeArguments().add(type);
    }
    newType = newParameterizedType; // use parameterized type
}
```